# How to copy data into empty table from another one by UPDATE?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have empty 'EMP_DANIL' table and the 'EMP' table with a data. How can I copy data from emp to emp_danil by UPDATE operator. Here is tables' view:
[emp_danil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2btB.png), [emp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwU8M.png)

```
UPDATE emp_danil
SET (empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, depto) = (SELECT * FROM emp);
```

Comment: You'd probably go with INSERT instead of UPDATE.

Comment: Yes, I thought about insert too, but the task is the copying data by update.

Comment: Many people here don't click to see images. Show us the sample table data and expected result as formatted text instead.

Comment: Update operation can modify the existing data. Your table emp_danil is empty so update can not help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to use an `update`. It sounds to me like you want to use an `insert`:

```
insert into emp_danil (
  empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, depto
) 
  SELECT * FROM emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Chris says, if you want to insert, you use `INSERT INTO` and specify the insert into columns and the select columns like this. Remeber that the amount of columns should be the same in both the insert into and the select part.

```
    INSERT INTO emp_danil (
    empno
    ,ename
    ,job
    ,mgr
    ,hiredate
    ,sal
    ,comm
    ,depto
    )
SELECT empno
    ,ename
    ,job
    ,mgr
    ,hiredate
    ,sal
    ,comm
    ,depto
FROM emp;
```